# Unsure how create method works - ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Ive created a twitter clone. I eventually found a way to get the create method to work. Im not 100% sure why it works though. I understand the if/else statement, its mainly the `@tweet.user = @user` i dont get. Could someone run through it? Thanks for any help.

```html
def create
  @user = current_user
  @tweet = Tweet.new(tweet_params)
  @tweet.user = @user
  authorize @tweet

  if @tweet.save
    redirect_to user_tweets_path
  else
    redirect_to user_tweets_path
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@tweet.user = @user` is setting the user on the tweet. It's essentially creating the relationship between `@user` and `@tweet`by setting `@tweet.user_id` to `@user.id`.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that, @moveson.